# Samsung 2233SW synmaster with DTH connection

Tags: display, hdmi, dvi, tv

I have a [Samsung 2233SW syncmaster](http://www.samsung.com/ph/consumer/monitor-peripherals-printer/monitor/consumer-monitor/LS22CMZKFVA/XP) monitor, and with a [HDMI to DVI cable](http://www.ebay.in/itm/HDMI-To-DVI-D-Dual-Link-Cable-Gold-Plated-1-5-Meter-24-1-Pin-DVI-D-/200936951885?ssPageName=ADME:B:PPOPN:IN:1123) I was able to connect to a DTH set top box. Everything was working fine, until I connected the cable to my laptop's DVI port. Now I can see the laptop's screen on the monitor, but the DTH connection no longer works. I see only the initialization screen when the set top box is started, and then the blank screen.

I have tried almost everything, reset, changing the resolution but no luck. Is there any way to hard reset the monitor setting? Is there anything I should check?